# Why isn't this egrep invocation case sensitive?

Tags: grep, regex

I'm using the following egrep invocation as a filter for an ant build:

```
egrep '\[.*\]|BUILD|time\:'
```

The build.xml file has a huge number of empty or unimportant targets that I'm trying to filter out.  However, any of them that have "build" in the name are still showing up in the output:

```
s.properties.build.mode.default:
s.properties.build.mode:
      [jar] Building jar: <my jar path>.jar
      [jar] JARs are never empty, they contain at least a manifest file
build.latest.execute:
```

(Context: This is on RHEL5.)

Why is this regex matching in a case insensitive manner?

*In response to comments*:

```
user@host ~> echo $GREP_OPTIONS

user@host ~> type egrep
egrep is an alias for grep -E
user@host ~> alias egrep
egrep='grep -E'
```

Comment: a shot in the dark, but check your GREP_OPTIONS env variable, see if you have `-i` in there

Comment: Similarly, check that your `egrep` isn't somehow aliased to use `-i`. E.g., `type egrep` or `alias egrep`.

Comment: Okay, so your `egrep` is aliased to `grep -E`, which is weird in itself, since there's no need for such an alias (as `egrep` implicitly means `grep -E`). What is your `grep` aliased to then?

Comment: That was the problem - grep was aliased to `grep -i --color=auto`.  If you'd care to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your `grep` or `egrep` isn't aliased to use the `-i` option.